# Drop view from package

Tags: oracle, permissions

I have a user called DEPLOY defined with DBA role.
When logged on via SQL Developer the user can drop a view as follows:

```
DROP VIEW APP_USER.VIEW_NAME_VW CASCADE CONSTRAINTS
```

If I put the same statement inside of a package owned by DEPLOY, then it fails with 'ORA-00942: table or view does not exist'.

So it appears that the privileges granted via the DBA role do not extend to code executed by the package.
Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Privileges granted via **any** role, not just the DBA role, are not available in a definer's rights stored procedure.  Assuming you want a definer's rights procedure, you'd need to grant the `deploy` user permission to drop the role via a direct grant.  Most likely in this case since you're fine with `deploy` having the DBA role

```
grant drop any view
   to deploy;
```